# Why is an unwanted empty line output on running a PowerShell script from within a Windows batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

When I execute the following `hello.ps1` in PowerShell, I get an output like I would expect, a `Hello World!` with a newline.

```
#powershell script hello.ps1
"Hello World!"
```

Output of run

```
PS C:\test>.\hello.ps1
Hello World!
PS C:\test>
```

But when I call the script from a bat file, I get two (2) newlines output in Windows console.

```
:: Windows CMD script name: mytest.bat
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass hello.ps1
```

Now the output has two newlines, note the empty line after `Hello World!`.

```
C:\test>mytest.bat
Hello World!

C:\test
```

How can I avoid this second newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mandragor -

Firstly, that is not two lines, it's just one.
Secondly, this is not a PowerShell specific thing.

You are calling one shell from another, and both must provide you a response and return to interactive mode. Calling an external command for one shell to another must be processed by the called shell first and results returned from the called shell to the calling shell, then exit the called process, and that calling shell must complete its process and any stdout stuff, and exit that process.

- Double-clicking a bat/cmd file, starts cmd.exe, task manager shows
  that process is running
- In your bat/cmd you are calling another standalone exe, task manager
  shows that the process is running. It must execute and return stdout
  results, then close/exit.
- cmd.exe the completes, and returns its stdout stuff, if any, and places the cursor at the next line for more interactive work.

Hence, the two responses, only if you ask for cmd.exe stdout stuff will you see it, vs just null.

You'll always have one more line return to get you back to the calling process.

Also, point of note:

- Write-Host except in specific circumstances, and what you are doing
  is not one of them.
- You only need that bypass policy setting if you are in a restricted
  environment. RemoteSigned is now the PowerShell default, meaning all local scripts will run, and remote scripts must be signed.
- Simple strings should use single quotes in most cases. Double quotes
  are for expanding variable content and other formatting scenarios.

Try the same thing calling any other shell, you'll get the same results. Heck, even calling another bat/cmd from a bat/cmd.

Example:

Running mytest.bat in cmd.exe that only contains these two lines, to show that only 1 CRLF is actually returned, per process, then you get bat the interactive shell.

```
powershell -File D:\Temp\hello.ps1
call d:\temp\hello.bat

# Results
Hello World!

D:\Temp>call d:\temp\hello.bat

D:\Temp>echo 'Hello World!'
'Hello World!'

D:\Temp>
```

Comment: ok,  obviously i am not command line expert. Because what i tested was i simple echo "Hello World" in cmd exe and it returned of course without an extra new.line. So thanks for making clear that this is a CMD:exe issue.  Yes i got confused by that, because the unix shell doesn't behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your powershell script like this:

```
#powershell script hello.ps1 
if ($args[0] -eq "cmd")  {
  write-host "Hello World!" -nonewline
} 
else {
  "Hello World!"
}
```

Then change the caller batch file:

```
@echo off
powershell -executionpolicy Bypass TheNameOfPowershellScript.ps1 "cmd"
```

Now when run from cmd use the caller batch file and from powershell directly use the ps1 script. It will give the expected result(Tested).